# export to csv without postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I need to find a way to export data to csv file without post back by using some jquery script.

I am trying to accomplish this by using ajax, below is the code:

```
public ActionResult  ExportDealerData(int shopId, int? siteId, int dealerId, DateTime? frmDate, DateTime? toDate, string fileName)
{
     string csvexport = ExportToCsv
         .CreateInstance(shopinstance, null, null, shopInstanceDates, true)
         .ReturnCsvFile();

     return File(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csvexport), "csv", "test.csv");
}
```

jquery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: oAxn.ds,
  data: JSON.stringify(oAxn.p(graphsDrpDwn)),
  success: function (graphData) {
       window.location = "/stealth/ExportDealerData?file=" + "test.csv";
  }
}


<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkMetricExport" CssClass="exportCsv composite" OnClientClick="YC.ajaxCall('dealerexport','dealerTab','','','');return false;" runat="server" Text="Export CSV" />
```

this is executing without any errors, however the file is not at all getting created.
It doesnt even shows that save file dialogue option box.

can somebody advsie what am I doing wrong??

Comment: You've tagged this as ASP.NET MVC, but it looks like you're using WebForms. Can you confirm?

Comment: Richard Ev - this is an actionresult, surely MVC?

Comment: its actually both. our html is not razor but we get some bits and pieces of data from controller using ajax calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way to do this - AJAX calls expect HTML, XML or JSON - you are returning a text file.

You don't really need an AJAX call for this at all. Just make your action a 'GET' and provide a link to that action on your page.  If you don't want a new page to open, you just append the appropriate headers to force it to download.

MVC does not have the idea of a postback - a GET request is just another request.

Comment: thanks for the response.can u advise what is kind of link to be provided to that action method? can u give me an example pls?

Comment: I cannot use Html.Actionlink because the page is not razor, it is asp.net styled page also the action expects some parameters?

Comment: Then you just need to write some code to output the appropriate URL.  It'll be something like: www.yoursite.com/ControllerName/ExportDealerData/?siteID=1....etc